# How is environment diagram implemented on computer hardware?

Tags: functional-programming, stack, environment

I'm learning [this python course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ro5S8b2Sx4) from UC Berkeley and come across the concept of **environment diagram**, which consists of frames that are similar with function call stacks (both are created with new function call) but have two big differences:

- In environment diagram variable in current frame can trace its value along the chain of frames (i.e.: environment), but variables (except global ones) in call stack only have function scope;
- Every frame in environment diagram has a parent frame, which can be different from the caller frame, while call stack only knows its return address to the caller;

I totally understand the mechanism of call stack and associated assembly code. But couldn't understand how the environment diagram model can be implemented on hardware?

examples:

[image: environment diagram]

[image: call stack diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Environment diagrams don't seem to exist outside of that Berkeley course. They seem to be more of a theoretical comprehension tool than an implementation strategy, as opposed to the call stack wich was invented at the dawn of Computer Science for its highly efficient properties.

if you would try to implement enviroment diagrams, you would probably maintain a stack of dictionary structures for each frame with variable-value bindings.